# Как правильно организовать историю денежного оборота?

Tags: php, база-данных, архитектура

Как правильно организовать историю денежного оборота?
Есть некая интересная задачка, которую я уже на протяжении очень долгого времени не могу красиво порешать.
Это реализация структуры финансового учета в проекте.

Давайте представим, что нужно сделать раздел "История денежного оборота", где будет выводиться список движения финансов с более-менее подробной информацией, например вот так:

> - Пользователь Вася перевел $10 пользователю Пете  Пользователь Вася
> - вывел $100 через систему "Приват Банк" Пользователь Петя перевел Вам
> - $15 Активация в тарифный план "Старт" за $25 Оплата $15 за услугу
> - "Смена логина" Оплата $100 за услугу "Поднять объявление в топ".
> - Квартира на сутки №1, Квартира на сутки №2, Квартира на сутки №3,
> - Квартира на сутки №4

Самая основная проблема заключается в том, что эту информацию нужно хранить не статично, а брать из других таблиц, для того, чтобы если Вася или Петя поменял логин, у всех в историях это изменилось. (Примеры взяты из головы, поэтому особо не обращайте внимание на конкретику).

**Теперь более детальный пример**

К примеру есть следующие типы услуг:

> - Поднять объявления в топ
> - Сменить логин
> - Купить подписку на "тарифный план"
> - Оплатить заказ товара

Задача: зафиксировать идентификаторы сущностей, которые фигурируют в заказе и отобразить из.

Рассмотрим на примере "Поднять объявления в топ" и "Купить подписку на 'тарифный план'".
Наша задача записать где-то список id из таблицы объявлений и id из таблицы тарифных планов, чтобы получить необходимые данные для рендера.

Проблема в том, что одним запросом историю денежного оборота не собрать, так как на основе типа услуги нужно узнавать к какой таблице относятся записанные id. От сюда выйдет, что мы может достать только список всех операций, а потом для каждой операции в цикле исходя из условия делать запрос в нужные таблицы, чтобы получить информацию с чем мы вообще работаем.

Тоесть если у нас задача отобразить 100 записей, то на каждую запись будет по 1 запросу и это выходит более 100 запросов в бд для рендера страницы. Как-то не хорошо.

Собственно поделитесь пожалуйста советом по реализации...

Answer (score 1):

А если логин хранить в массиве?
Т.е. Вася с самого начала в Name[0]  это стандартно, если он поменял индекс будет 1,2,3.4,....,n
Тоесть создать массив или ArrayList и считать что у этого пользователя имя такое то до Null елементов.
Прмер Вася(0), Василий(1) ,Null,null,null,null,....,null

Comment: И очевидно что новое имя это Василий, так как потом идёт null елементы

Comment: тут ключевой момент в выборке данных. Что если мы к примеру подняли в топ 10 или 100 объявлений ?